# Rotate and delete an element from a list

Tags: list, prolog, element

I would like to run through a list A and delete any element from that list that has the same Key as the pair located in the List B then create a new List C out of it.

I got it working only for the Head, but I can't figure out how to cycle through the Tail for the List B

```
diff(A, B, C).
```

If I do this query:

```
diff([(a,b),(k1,_),(c,d),(k2,_)],[(k1,_),(k2,_)],L).
```

I should get the output:

```
L = [(a,b),(c,d),]
```

This is what i got so far:

```
diff([],[(K,_)|_], []).
diff([(K,_)|T],[(K,_)|_],M3) :- 
   diff(T, [(K,_)|_], M3), !.
diff([H|T], [(K,_)|_], [H|M3]) :- 
   diff(T, [(K,_)|_], M3).
```

If I run my query through what I got, I get the following output:

```
L = [(a,b),(c,d),(k2,_37227)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make some fixes to your predicate `diff/3`
1- The second term in your base clause don't need to be instantiated, you just stop when your list is empty.
2- The idea in your general clause is copy the head of your original list to your final list if this element is **NOT** member of your keys list.
It looks like this:

```
diff([], _, []).
diff([(K,_)|Tail], Keys, M3):-
             member((K,_), Keys), !,
             diff(Tail, Keys, M3).
diff([H|Tail], Keys, [H|M3]):-
              diff(Tail, Keys, M3).
```

Consult:

```
?- diff([(a,b),(k1,_),(c,d),(k2,_)],[(k1,_),(k2,_)],L).
L = [ (a, b), (c, d)].
```

Comment: Oh i see so instead of comparing each head element of the second list with the head of the first list, i should just check if the head of the first list is in the second list. Thanks for the help !